# How to deploy multiple compiled solidity with web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, solc

So I have this codes

```js
  const MultiSigWalletFactory = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "MultiSigWalletFactory.sol"), "utf8");
  const Factory = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "Factory.sol"), "utf8");
  const MultiSigWallet = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "MultiSigWallet.sol"), "utf8");
  const input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
      "Factory.sol": Factory,
      "MultiSigWallet.sol": MultiSigWallet,
      "MultiSigWalletFactory.sol": MultiSigWalletFactory,
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['*'],
        },
      },
    },
  };
  const output = solc.compile(input);
```

it will output bytecode and ABI for each file.

How can I deploy this to the blockchain using web3?

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: the latest version from `npm install web3`

Comment: Please run `npm ls web3` and tell us what you get.

Comment: it's `web3@1.2.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this **for each contract** (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const fs   = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const NODE_ADDRESS  = "your ethereum node URL";
const PRIVATE_KEY   = "your private key";
const CONTRACT_NAME = "your contract name (not file name)";
const CONTRACT_ARGS = ["constructor argument 1", "constructor argument 2", ...];
const ARTIFACTS_DIR = "<the relative path from this script to your abi & bin folder>";

async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, account, transaction) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
                gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3),
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function run() {
    const web3        = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
    const account     = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const path        = __dirname + "/" + ARTIFACTS_DIR + "/" + CONTRACT_NAME;
    const abi         = fs.readFileSync(path + ".abi", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const bin         = fs.readFileSync(path + ".bin", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const contract    = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    const options     = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: CONTRACT_ARGS};
    const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
    const receipt     = await send(web3, account, transaction);
    console.log(CONTRACT_NAME, "deployed at", receipt.contractAddress);
    if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I have to deploy each compiled dependency?

Comment: @bbnn: What does "compiled dependency" mean? You need to deploy each contract.

Comment: The solidity files I have are MultiSigWalletFactory.sol, Factory.sol, and MultiSigWallet.sol.
I compiled them with solc.js and for each file it has different interface and bytecode.

Comment: @bbnn: You can take your `output.abi` and `output.bytecode`, and use them as the values of `abi` and `bin` in my script (or alternatively, place them inside two files named `YourContractName.abi` and `YourContractName.bin`, and then set `ARTIFACTS_DIR` to point to the folder were you place these two files).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have another question about the interface and bytecode output footprint. Should I keep them safe? or it doesn't matter as long as I have the private key of the contract creator address?

Comment: @bbnn: The only thing you should keep safe is the private key. The bytecode will be visible to everyone once you deploy the contract, whether you like it or not. And in fact, you should strive also for your source code to be properly visible, for example, by verifying it on etherscan after deploying your contract. Why? Because the general idea about interacting with contracts on the blockchain is that you know what's in them (imagine yourself signing a "physical" contract without reading it first).

Comment: Your codes worked fine only on first nonce. I'm getting `the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 1 tx has nonce of: 0` now. How can I get the nonce?

Comment: @bbnn: In the `options` object, add field setting `nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount({from: account.address})`.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it should be `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)`
but for some reasons it returns 0. is it due to ganache?

Comment: @bbnn: Wait a second, are you trying to call `run()` in a loop??? I wrote specifically that this script is for deploying a single contract. How can there be more than "first nonce"???

Comment: no I'm not looping that, I only deploy the MultiSigFactory since it is where all the imports are called.
I tried to do it on the kovan node, it works fine. But it doesn't work with ganache. ganache always returns 0 from `getTransactionCount` maybe a bug from ganache?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I use the PK from ganache without `0x` while web3 needs it with `0x`

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Web3 Instance

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://SERVER_IP:PORT"));
```

- From the compiled input i.e. `output` extract `bytecode` and `abi`

```
const FactoryABI = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Factory'].interface);
const MultiSigWalletABI = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':MultiSigWallet'].interface);
const MultiSigWalletFactoryABI = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':MultiSigWalletFactory'].interface);

const FactoryBytecode = output.contracts[':Factory'].bytecode;
const MultiSigWalletBytecode = output.contracts[':MultiSigWallet'].bytecode;
const MultiSigWalletFactoryBytecode = output.contracts[':MultiSigWalletFactory'].bytecode;
```

- Deploy the contracts using web3

```
const FactoryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(FactoryABI);
// Deploy FactoryContract
FactoryContract.deploy({
    data: FactoryBytecode,
    arguments: ["If it takes arguments in constructor pass those over here"]
}).send({
    from: "ACCOUNT THROUGH WHICH IT SHOULD BE DEPLOYED",
    gas: "GAS_LIMIT"
});

Similarly, MultisigWallet & MultisigwalletFactory can be deployed.
```

Comment: Prior to executing this script, `ACCOUNT THROUGH WHICH IT SHOULD BE DEPLOYED` has to be unlocked on the node that this user is communicating with (via an RPC request to the node, assuming that this API is enabled on the node). Note this unlocking your account on a node is not recommend, since anyone hacking that node may exploit your account at will. So while this method may be good enough when testing on your private network (e.g., via Truffle & Ganache), it is not recommended for operational mode.